# How I can get data from pivot table in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I want to get all the tags that belongs to their domains but I couldn't find an answer how I can do that.

I think the solution is something in this way:

```
$domain = Domains::findOrFail($id);
```

realation:

```
public function domains() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Domains', 'domain_tag', 'tags_id', 'domains_id')->withPivot('tags_id'); }
```

and in my view:

```
            @foreach($domains as $domain)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $domain->pivot->name }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Thanks for taking time.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a structure something like this. If you are following db naming conventions properly then you should not need anything else.. You should create different tables/models for tags and domains. and then you pivot table should be like domains_tags( id, domain_id, tag_id)

```
class Domain extends Model
{

    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}



class Tag extends Model
{

    public function domains(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Domain');
    }
}


$domain = App\Domain::find(1);

foreach ($domain->tags as $tag) {
    //
}
```

Comment: I allready have that. It's more that I want all tags that belongs to the domain. I think there is a laravel function that can give me all the tags belongs to the correct domain_id

Comment: $domain->tags only gives you the tags that belong to this particular domain and not all